# silvershop PaymentExpress yml set end point to UAT

Tags: yaml, payment-gateway, silvershop

i set up a silvershop with silverstrpe however im getting a \ User Access Error \
when proceeding to payment.

Talking to support they recommend:

*make sure you are using the UAT end point - https://uat.paymentexpress.com/pxaccess/pxpay.aspx*

how do i set it up in yml file?
my current yml settings here:

```
Payment:
  allowed_gateways:
    - 'PaymentExpress_PxPay'

GatewayInfo:
  PaymentExpress_PxPay:
    parameters:
      username: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'      
      password: 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that i just need to point to a test environment

```
parameters:    
   testMode: true
```